# Does using New to Reinit an Object cause a Memory Leak in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks

Hopefully this question isn't so basic that it causes me to lose reputation points.  I really have searched some and have not found a good answer, however.

I have an object that is used by a state machine that is executed during a timer tick interrupt.  Can I use New() to reinitialize this object each time the state machine gets back to the Init state, or do I need a separate Reset() method?

Here is a simplified example.  Am I leaking memory here?

```
Private my_state As Integer
Private my_object As my_class
Private WithEvents my_timer As Timer

Private Sub My_Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles my_timer.Tick
    Select Case my_state
        Case 0
            my_object = New my_class()
            my_state = 1
        Case 1
            my_object.Do_Stuff()
            my_state = 2
        Case 2
            my_object.Do_More_Stuff()
            my_state = 3
        Case 3
            Take_My_Object(my_object)
            my_state = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub New` is called once and only once for an object. It doesnt reinitialize an object, it creates a *new* one as the name implies.  What you are doing is creating a new `my_class` instance and replacing `my_object`  each time, the old one will be queued for GC.  Depending on what it is and does, it should dispose of resources it allocates internally.

Comment: In my case I wrote New so that it initializes the object when it is created.  If the old object gets garbage collected when I create the new object, it seems that I'm not leaking then?  Is there a another performance reason why it's worse to keep making new objects and destroying the old ones than to make a separate method to reinitialize the object?

Comment: `I wrote New so that it initializes the object when it is created` thats what it does for everyone.  You may or may not be leaking resources depending on what `my_class` does. You wont have a leak *just* from creating/replacing `my_object` though if the timer interval is short enough you could be creating them faster than GC can clean up,

Comment: Thanks for the info.  My total state machine time is ~10 seconds.  Is that a large amount of time compared to the garbage collection?